# Postgres / SQL: How to group returned rows by a column value?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express

So I have this table `employee_info`:

| branch_id | employee_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | "Barack" | "Obama" |
| 2 | 2 | "Johnny" | "Depp" |
| 2 | 3 | "Emma" | "Watson" |
| 4 | 4 | "Daniel" | "Radcliffe" |
| 4 | 5 | "Leonardo" | "DiCaprio" |
| 7 | 17 | "Denzel" | "Washington" |
| 4 | 13 | "Keanu" | "Reeves" |
| 7 | 15 | "Samuel" | "Jackson" |
| 7 | 19 | "Brendan" | "Fraser" |
| 7 | 20 | "Kanye" | "West" |

I'm using node / express with json middleware to retrieve rows, so if I do `SELECT * FROM employee_info` I get

```json
[
  {branch_id: 2, employee_id: 1, first_name: 'Barack', last_name: 'Obama'},
  {branch_id: 2, employee_id: 2, first_name: 'Johnny', last_name: 'Depp'},
  ...
]
```

But what I want is to group entries by `branch_id`, to get an array like:

```json
[
  { branch_id: 2, employees: [{employee_id: 1, first_name: 'Barack', last_name: 'Obama'}, ...] }
  { branch_id: 4, employees: [{...}] }
  { branch_id: 7, employees: [{...}] }
]
```

I can do something like:

```sql
SELECT branch_id, ARRAY_AGG (employee_id) employee_ids FROM employee_info GROUP BY branch_id
```

Which is oh so close as it gives me:

```json
[
    {
        "branch_id": 7,
        "employee_ids": [
            17,
            15,
            19,
            20,
            10,
            14
        ]
    },
    ...
```

But I'm stumped as to how to get an array of objects nested in the `employees` property. I know I could do this on the node server by making subsequent calls, but I'd prefer to do it all in one query. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using a combination of `JSON_AGG` and `json_build_object`

```sql
SELECT branch_id, JSON_AGG (json_build_object('employee_id',employee_id,'first_name',first_name,'last_name', last_name)) employees FROM employee_info GROUP BY branch_id
```

Any other approaches are welcome.